# Error: An unknown error occurred while sending the password reset email Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I got this error when I'm trying to reset user password thru firebase auth. please help me I really need it [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPHeS.png)

Comment: Check the JavaScript console of your browser for errors that may be relevant. If none are showing and the error persists, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

This could have been a platform issue, at the time.
Make sure you've got reliable internet connectivity, refresh the page, then try again.
If it fails, check Firebase status page here: https://status.firebase.google.com/.

---

In addition, some advice I'd give;
You're exposing too much sensitive data on the image that you've linked to. We don't need to see the email addresses or UIDs of your users.
Also, it's always best when you attach images to the question itself, rather than linking to an external source.